# Adding a column of p-values from Anova test of the slopes to a merged gtsummary table

Tags: gtsummary, quantile-regression

I used this guide to create a merged table of rq fits
https://yuzar-blog.netlify.app/posts/2022-12-01-quantileregression/

`tbl_merge(     tbls = list(       tbl_regression(q10, se = "nid") %>% bold_p(),        tbl_regression(q50, se = "nid") %>% bold_p(),       tbl_regression(q90, se = "nid") %>% bold_p() ),     tab_spanner = c("QR 10%", "QR 50%", "QR 90%")   )`

I want to add a column of p-values from Anova test of the slopes

`anova(q10 , q50 , q90, joint = FALSE)`

How can it be done?

I tried saving the p values as a vector and adding it to the table
p_vals <- as.numeric(anova(q10, q50, q90, joint = FALSE)$table$pvalue)
but didn't manage to bind the vector as a column

Thank you!